# Trying to make a youtube search function on my website with the youtube api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, youtube-api

As the title says, I'm trying to make a youtube search function on my website. This is what I've got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#searchbutton").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var searchInput = $("#search");
    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",
        {
            part: 'snippet',
            maxResults: 1,
            q: searchInput,
            key: 'my_key'
        }, function (data) {

                console.log(data.items.id.videoId);

        }
    );
});
```

});

When I press #searchbutton, it puts the input in 'searchInput' and then it puts searchInput in 'q'. Here is my html-code:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="search"/>
<button type="submit" id="searchbutton">Find</button>
</form>
```

For now I'm just trying to make the videoId output in the console. The problem is that when I click on the searchbutton, my whole website just doesn't respond anymore. I can still use other websites at that moment, but my websites just won't respond anymore. I know that the variable 'searchInput' is the problem, because whenever I type something like 'dog' in 'q', it will just give me a videoId about a dog video. Does anyone know why 'searchInput' makes my website not respond? Or is there maybe a better way to do this whole youtube search thing?

Comment: data.items sounds like it would be an array... did you try accessing one value within it?

Comment: additionally, you probably want the input's value, not the input itself.

Comment: Have you already looked at the [sample documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#examples)?